# Can't get server to respond to SSH

Tags: wireless, networking, server, ssh

I am the admin of a private server and I'm pretty new to administration. SSH was working fine until I upgraded to 14.04. Something went wrong with the upgrade so I downgraded to 13.04. Now SSH doesn't work, that is, when a remote tries to connect, the server doesn't respond.

- I used `ifconfig` to double check the server IP.
- The network card (wireless) works fine. I can `ping 8.8.8.8` without
  a problem.
- If I `sudo service ssh status` I see a process. When I `ps -ef | grep sshd` I see the process running.
- Doing a `netstat -ln` I can see `tcp ... 0.0.0.0:22`.
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` shows password auth is enabled.
- There is a `~/.ssh` directory with a `'known_hosts` file in it.
- On the server, I can `ssh localhost` and get a response.

Anyone know what could be happening? What should I do next?

Comment: Is SSH the only thing that's not working? Are you sure you're using the right IP address?

Comment: could it be due to keys ? `~/.ssh/` is that folder there?

Comment: Could it be, after upgrading, that the upgrade process asked you to *disable* password logins? So you would have to do the according changes in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

Comment: If I try to run the ssh script in init.d directly, nothing happens.  But if I run `sudo service ssh status`, then I get an output.  On my system, it says "ssh start/running, process 22120".

Comment: Can you ssh to yourself from the server? As in: `ssh localhost`?

Comment: I can `ssh localhost`.  There is a .ssh directory.  known_hosts is encrypted.  I know there's a way to look at it.  Maybe my remote IP isn't in there?

Comment: I think there is a problem with `sshd` initializing. I am not certain, but I don't believe `ssh localhost` is a definitive test that the daemon is up and fully functional. If the process is hung in a loop, it could still show as an active process. Requesting status from the upstart initialization script, and not getting an answer, is indicative of a problem with the daemons run state.

Comment: `sudo service ssh status` does give me a response and it is the process that says it's running sshd.  sshd_config has password auth enabled.  pinging the server from the remote works fine.

Comment: Is port 22 opened in your firewall?

Comment: @Oli That was it!  Make it an answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1):

It was the firewall on the server.  The update process must have closed port 22.  I used `ufw` to open it.  Thanks to @Oli for the suggestion.